# Repeated Measures ANOVA that is NOT fully factorial

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I'm trying to design an experiment using repeated measures ANOVA. I have one (possibly two) factors I want to test. I have 5 factor levels that I want to show that there is a difference between. I will have 8 subjects. So ideally, I would test each of the 5 factor levels on each subject (randomizing the order of course)

However, the issue is that due to time constraints, we can't test all 5 factor levels on each patient, so we are looking to test only 3 or 4 factor levels on each patient. Is there a method that would be useful for this?

To word it in a different way, I want to apply each factor level to 6 (or some number less than 8) out of the 8 subjects, instead of applying each factor level to all 8 subjects. This is because it takes too long to apply all 5 factor levels to a subject.